# NetworkManager : restrict a connection to USB Ethernet wired dongles

Tags: networkmanager, nmcli

With NetworkManager I want to restrict a connection to USB Ethernet wired dongles.

In the documentation, https://developer-old.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nm-settings-nmcli.html:

> `interface-name`: A list of interface names to match. Each element is a shell wildcard pattern

I try using the property `connection.interface-name` to `enx*` but when I try:

```bash
# nmcli c up usb-dongle ifname enx00249b000000
Error: device 'enx00249b000000' not compatible with connection 'usb-dongle': The interface names of the device and the connection didn't match.
```

Any idea?

EDIT1:
I need an equivalent to a systemd-networkd [Match.Name=enx*](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html#%5BMatch%5D%20Section%20Options)

Answer (score 0):

By "restrict", do you mean that you want to prevent USB WiFi dongles from being used?

The way I block USB thumb drives on my company's workstations is by blocking the insertion of the module.  Perhaps you can do the same?  Create a file in /etc/modprobe.d, name it something like "block_usb_wifi.conf" with the following contents:

```
install wsusbcore :
```

This will prevent the driver from being loaded when the USB stick is inserted.  Note that this should block all USB WiFi devices for all users.

Comment: In fact, I need an equivalent to a systemd-networkd [Match.Name=enx*](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html#%5BMatch%5D%20Section%20Options) to apply a specific configuration to all the USB dongles